# In SharePoint 2007, is there a way to allow users to see folder names, but not the contents of the folder?

Tags: permissions, folder

One of the SharePoint sites I have has a Document Library called Requested Requirements. Withing that document library, a folder is created for each new request that comes in. I would like people to be able to see the names of the folders (so that they can see what we are working on), but not to be able to view the files contained within the folder itself. I have modified the permissions of the folder so that only the site owners can view it, but this means that a non-owner cannot see anything within the Requested Requirements library. Does anyone know how to do this or if it is even possible?

For the record, I am on the web-only version of SharePoint 2007. We will be moving to SharePoint 2013 in Q2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

Option A
Set Unique permissions for the folder with the read access to the people. This way they can see the names of the folder you are working on. Inside the folder, whenever you uploaded a new document , set unique permissions for those documents by restricting access to only you/your team. This way the folder remains visible only to the people while when they click and go inside the folder in sharepoint , they are not able to see any documents.

or

Option B
Create a webpart page and add the document library view through a dataview webpart using sharepoint designer. Make a query to list the folders within the library and remove all the hyperlinks through xslt formatting. Share this webpage with your users. They will only see the folders you are working on without anyway for them to browse these folders.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I do not have access to SharePoint designed, but your first option will work. Fortunately, there are only a couple documents per folder.